# Issue in displaying the data to view page in laravel, but the value is getting passed through url and its not getting displayed in the view page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Find below the controller code, Here I'm getting the data's passed in the url and I need the data entered through the form to be displayed / printed in the view page..

Controller Code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
     {
        $domainname = Input::get('domainname');
        $tld = Input::get('tld');
        $url='https://httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=711757&api-key=74miSZPgYkkc108Ptmeo5Q8iDTtKk3xi&domain-name=';
        $ch = curl_init($url.$domainname.'&tlds='.$tld);
        711757&api-key=74miSZPgYkkc108Ptmeo5Q8iDTtKk3xi&domain-name='.$domainname.'&tlds='.$tld.'&suggest-alternative=true');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $final_data = json_decode($result,true);
        dd($final_data);
        return view('clientlayout.main.tld',compact('final_data'));
}
```

tld.blade.php:

```
  {{print_r($final_data)}}
```

When I use the above code to print the data in view page, it just prints as "11".

Route code:

```
  Route::get('tld','TldController@create')->name('domain.create');
```

Kindly help me with this to solve the issue and print the data in the view page.

Answer (score 0):

$dataFromForm = $request->FieldNameFromForm

This will allow you to get the data from the form, assuming you use a POST or GET request.

In the form named "greeting":

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

In controller:

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
```

Comment: Fine.. Still I have an issue in printing the data to my view. can you suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Fine. I got the value as below : 
{
  "decksys.info": {
    "classkey": "dominfo",
    "status": "available"
  }
} .... I need to print the "decksys.info" and the value of status from the above data